# Why is it not accepting the assignment operator and how do i fix it

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

```
Sub searchfilter(ByVal mytextbox As TextBox, ByVal myfield As String)
    If Not source1.DataSource = ExcelDB.DataSource Then
        source1.DataSource = ExcelDB.DataSource
    End If
    ExcelDB.DataSource = source1
    Dim searchstring As String = ""
    If mytextbox.Text = "" Then
        source1.RemoveFilter()
    Else
        source1.Filter = myfield & " = '" & mytextbox.Text & "'"
        addquery(myfield & "= '" & mytextbox.Text & "'")
    End If
End Sub
```

In the if not statement it says that the = operation is not a datatype

Comment: Please describe your issue more and formate code as code.

Comment: Thats not the exact error message.  What is `source1` and even `ExcelDB` for that matter.  What type of control or object?

Comment: You can't declare and assign a variable (only a constant) in one statement, so this won't work: `Dim searchstring As String = ""`

Comment: @Rory: actually you can and you should.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas This is also tagged Excel-VBA (which is why I saw it) and you can't in that.

Answer (score 0):

As Plutonix said, that can't be the actual error message, but the main problem is that in VB you don't use '=' for testing identity of reference types, and I'm guessing that 'DataSource' is a reference type instance, so you must use 'Is':

```
If Not source1.DataSource Is ExcelDB.DataSource Then
    source1.DataSource = ExcelDB.DataSource
End If
```

or with newer syntax:

```
If source1.DataSource IsNot ExcelDB.DataSource Then
    source1.DataSource = ExcelDB.DataSource
End If
```